# Get the maximum value among OpenMP threads in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a do loop which updates T value and calculates the maximum difference during the iteration, called dumax.

I need to initialize dumax, so I set it to be

```
firstprivate
```

Then I will not be able to use:

```
reduction(max: dumax)
```

Reduction operator seems to accept private variable. 
Then how can I get the maximum value of dumax before I end the parallel?

My program is shown below:

```
DUMAX=0.0D0
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(PRIVATE), SHARED(T_R, T_B), FIRSTPRIVATE(DUMAX)
            !$OMP DO 
            DO I=2, N-1, 2
                DO J=2, N-1, 2
                    T_OLD=T_B(I,J)
                    T_B(I,J)=0.25*(T_R(I,J-1)+T_R(I,J+1)+T_R(I+1,J)+&
                                    T_R(I-1,J)-DX**2*S(I,J))
                    DUMAX=MAX(DUMAX, ABS(T_OLD-T_B(I,J)))
                END DO
            END DO
            !$OMP END DO 
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set `dumax` to `firstprivate`. Reduction variables should be `shared`. Make it shared and then use `reduction(max: dumax)`. Your initialization will be kept.

Comment: So what is the meaning of using firstprivate, since the initialization would be kept?

Comment: @ShiqiHe They are a special kind of `private`, not of `shared`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304760/how-are-firstprivate-and-lastprivate-different-than-private-clauses-in-openmp For a `shared` variable you don't need to care about the value of the first or the last thread, there is only one value.